# (xrandr Question) Problem with displaying Ubuntu in native resolution

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, display-resolution

If you can help me, I will be virtually in your debt.

---

Rather long story short I have a Nvidia 8800GTS, and all the drivers result in a 'blinking cursor' on startup. I've tried repository installations, website installations, literally everything, and I had the same problem on Windows 7 which was my previous OS.

My intentions are to get VGA to it's native monitor resolution of 1920x1080.

I am currently using a DVI to VGA adapter as there is no VGA port on my card.

5 hours later, I've made it this far.

```
tsgg@tsgg:~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1024x768       76.0* 


tsgg@tsgg:~$ cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync


tsgg@tsgg:~$ xrandr --newmode  "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default


tsgg@tsgg:~$ xrandr --addmode default 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default


tsgg@tsgg:~$ xrandr --output default --mode 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: screen cannot be larger than 1024x768 (desired size 1920x1080)


tsgg@tsgg:~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1024x768       76.0* 
1920x1080_60.00   60.0
```

Thanks in advance, I will leave my PC Specs below.

AMD Phenom x4 965

MS-7640

Nvidia 8800GTS

2TB SG Drive

2x4GB Corsair Vengeance @ 1600mhz

TSGG

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find your monitor name, such as `VGA1` and `DVI-0`, which you can do with this command:

```
xrandr | grep " connected " | awk '{ print$1 }'
```

Now use the output of that command instead of the `default` you used in your `xrandr` commands.

Comment: I did find that out later but my resolution remained at 1024x768, despite clearly saying it was 1920x1080. Turns out it was an issue with my graphic card's memory. 

Doing this does work on my second computer which helps to list unknown resolutions, so I'll  mark this as my answer, as I couldn't find this info on any Ubuntu forums, thank you, I will use this command in the future! :)